# Can't get .getJSON to work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have trouble sending and receiving JSON object using $.getJSON()

In **index.html**, I send a get JSON request to send an object and retrieve data

```
var newtable = {
"query":"create",
"num":"2"
};
var crypt=JSON.stringify(newtable);
$.getJSON('php/table_manager.php',crypt,function(data){alert(data);});
```

In **php/table_manager.php**, I write a script to simply return the JSON object:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST);
$return = json_encode($data);
echo $return;
```

However, `$return` is null. Please help me fix this.

Comment: Have you taken a look at what the `$_POST` variable contains? [json_decode](http://au1.php.net/json_decode) returns null if it can't decode the data you give it, and json_encode might just be cooperating in storing a null value. I bet `$_POST` isn't what you should be decoding - you may need to do something _with it_ to get the value you're after though. There may be something inside there you need to work with.

Comment: hmm I guess that's why. So how can I retrieve the JSON object in php?

Comment: I don't know how `$_POST` works or I'd be leaving an answer. Take a look at the `$_POST` variable though within your script and research its docs. It's been years since I last used PHP, so I've forgotten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit an object to $.getJSON it's unpacked by jQuery into separate variables that are sent to the server. So, at the server you'll have `$_GET['query'] == "create"` and `$_GET['num'] == "2"`

All you need do is json_encode($_GET) and send it back - no need to decode it first.

Comment: `$.getJSON` sends a GET request, so your answer should be referring to `$_GET` not `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

The function `$.getJSON` of jQuery's ajax suite sends a request with type 'GET'.

php/table_manager.php which is:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST);
$return = json_encode($data);
echo $return;
```

tries to retrieve the POST value through `$_POST`, change that to `$_GET` and you are good to go!